# URL works from browser but returns 500 from console app using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, console-application

Trying to reach a web service URL, works (returns status code 200 as expected) without issue with simple GET from a browser but when executing through console application it is returns status code of 500? I suspect it's proxy or DNS issue but unsure...

Here's request creation from console app:

```
// webRequestUrl has been modified
const string webRequestUrl = "http://0.0.0.0/communication/?id={0}&status=70"

var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(string.Format(webRequestUrl, invalidSseLead.LeadId));

try
{
    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (webResponse != null && webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (var textStream = new StreamWriter("updateQuery.sql", true))
            {
                // Write some text
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // Report exception
}
```

Have checked request URL being generated and it's fine, stumped why it works from browser but not console app?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you grab the result of string.Format and paste it to a browser does it work?

Comment: Yep have tested this and it's working no problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance. Turned out the problem was in fact with the URL, one worked however a different one being generated was throwing the exception.

+1 to MSMS - I really needed to copy and paste out the exact URL being generated rather than using one with test data

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the site rejecting programmatic access such that you maybe have to fake your user agent using the following?

```
webRequest.UserAgent = "some normal browser user agent string";
```

Comment: thanks for the help, tried setting user agent however still returning same exception